# Angluarjs http.post does not work

Tags: angularjs, http

It's my first project with Angluar.js, I tried to post an object (personne), but it did not work. Is there a problem with my code?

```
myapp.controller('personCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.connexion = function(personne) {
    $http.post("http://localhost:8080/app/personne/testpost",$scope.personne)
        .success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
        });

    console.log('ca fonctionne');
});
```

Comment: On your post, use your var `personne` instead of `$scope.personne`.

Comment: **It doesn't work**, does not give anything to solve. Please post the exact error/non-required behavior.

Comment: if your TestPost(string name) is some like this.  try post(.. ... personne/testpost',{ name: personne})

Answer (score 0):

try this one .

```
$scope.connexion = function(personne) {
    $http.post("http://localhost:8080/app/personne/testpost",{personne : $scope.personne}).
        success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
        });

    console.log('ca fonctionne');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `$scope` as parameter on your post request, but you need to pass the parameter as object variable:

```
myapp.controller('personCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.connexion = function(personne) {
    $http.post("http://localhost:8080/app/personne/testpost",{persone: $scope.personne})
        .success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
        });

    console.log('ca fonctionne');
});
```

Check the angular documentation for [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).